# Why RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri could not work? [android API-8]

Tags: android, ringtone

This question could be duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801908/android-change-notification-ringtone) but I see some difference in code, so I put a new question.

Problem is that I cannot set picked ringtone in RingtonePicker. I use [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki), maybe it can cause such problems (though I doubt it).

I have Fragment with a button in it. When clicking on button a RingtonePicker is fired. User select ringtone and application saves it in SharedPreference. Next time when user open RingtonePicker, previously selected ringtone should be checked, and I can't do that.

Here is my Fragment

```
@EFragment(R.layout.pref_page)
public class PrefPage extends Fragment {

    @Pref
    MyPrefs_ myPrefs;

    @Click(R.id.ringtone_button)
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        String uri = myPrefs.beepUri().get();    

        if (uri != "") {      
                    Log.i("Log", "uri is " + uri);              
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                            getActivity(),
                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
                            Uri.parse(uri));
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            if (uri != null) {
                String uriString = uri.toString();
                Log.i("Log", "uriString is " + uriString);
                myPrefs.edit().beepUri().put(uriString).apply();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In two words question is - **why RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri is not working here?**

**UPDATED:**

I have WRITE_SETTINGS permission in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Comment: This question is a bit old now but, if you never ended up fixing the issue I have had a bit of experience with setting ringtones now. If you want to post the error you had, or if you can give a description of why it's not working I'd be happy to help. Otherwise, I'd love to see an answer to this question.

Comment: @Paradopolis No, I didn't have any errors. If no one know why this method could not work then I expect some piece of working code.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov: Maybe it requires the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS) for more info. Are you testing your codes on a rooted, non-rooted device, or emulator?

Answer (score 6):

Ok so I had the same issue as you. I am assuming that the Uri you are passing in is a file in your assets or from the disk that you are storing in a preference file. Working under this assumption, the issue is that you can't shove a Uri into the RingtoneManager and expect it to take it. The file uri should be coming from the content resolver.

I would love it if someone could tell me why that is exactly, but I'm not an expert so I'm accepting it as is for now. That being said, this code will let you take a Uri and set it as the default ringtone.

```
    //We get the Uri here fro ma file's absolute path.
    Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

    //We now create a new content values object to store all the information 
    //about the ringtone.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, chosenFile.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, chosenFile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, chosenFile.length());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(AudioColumns.ARTIST, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    values.put(AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Work with the content resolver now
    //First get the file we may have added previously and delete it, 
    //otherwise we will fill up the ringtone manager with a bunch of copies over time.
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(chosenFile.getAbsolutePath());
    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + chosenFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);

    //Ok now insert it
    Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

    //Ok now set the ringtone from the content manager's uri, NOT the file's uri
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
      context,
      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
      newUri
    );
```

Comment: //otherwise we will fill up the ringtone manager with a bunch of copies over time helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the permission to write in to settings in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Also post your logcat output.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I have this permission in manifest. And LogCat doesn't clarify anything since my application does not crash when launching RingtonePicker, it just does not select Ringtone I want from the list.

Comment: When you want to assign ringtone to a particular contact when why there is no need to this permission, android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS?