# Why am I writing settings without WRITE_SETTINGS permission

Tags: android

I have an application that changes the user's ringtones from time to time. I was running the application on my phone without issues, which is running 4.2.2, Android version 17. However when I was running the application, I had not set the permission yet. I put it up for alpha testing, and my friend immediately ran into the issue on version 8. I have corrected the issue and it is now fine, but I am still curious.

Is there a reason why I was able to run the application fine without the permission set, while someone else was not?

Comment: There is a related question, can you help this person figure out why his app is not working ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352416/why-ringtonemanager-setactualdefaultringtoneuri-could-not-work-android-api-8